# Build an artifact URL programmatically

Tags: artifactory

I am using scripts to open an artifact by querying it via REST API calls. After searching for an artifact, I get a uri using which I wanted to open a browser window and show that artifact there.
for ex., if the uri is

```
http://<hostname>/artifactory/api/storage/payload-repo/com/xxxx/payload-something/6.1.0.0-6/something.jar
```

i will replace 'api/storage' with 'simple' and replace jar name with null, to show it under simple browser. Now, I am trying to show that under a tree browser to show the hierarchy properly.

Could you guys help me in making a URL to show an artifact in a tree browser view automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Artifactory 3 URLs are not bookmarkable, while Artifactory 4 URLs are. So, if you didn't upgrade yet now it's the time. Once you are on 4, your URL will be:

`https://<hostname>/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/payload-repo/com/xxxx/payload-something/6.1.0.0-6/something.jar`

Comment: I am on "Artifactory Pro Power Pack 3.0.4 (rev. 30058)". Will try upgrading it and get back. Thanks for the response.